# How to connect my Parachain and Ethereum to ChainBridge?

Tags: parachain, ethereum, bridge, chainbridge

How can I make ChainBridge to work with my parachain collator? Is there a documentation for such process?

all the settings are inside the chainbridge/config.json file(https://github.com/ChainSafe/ChainBridge#chain-implementations):

```
{
  "chains": [
    {
      "name": "eth",
      "type": "ethereum",
      "id": "0",
      "endpoint": "ws://localhost:8545",
      "from": "0xff93B45308FD417dF303D6515aB04D9e89a750Ca",
      "opts": {
        "bridge": "0x62877dDCd49aD22f5eDfc6ac108e9a4b5D2bD88B",
        "erc20Handler": "0x3167776db165D8eA0f51790CA2bbf44Db5105ADF",
        "erc721Handler": "0x3f709398808af36ADBA86ACC617FeB7F5B7B193E",
        "genericHandler": "0x2B6Ab4b880A45a07d83Cf4d664Df4Ab85705Bc07",
        "gasLimit": "1000000",
        "maxGasPrice": "20000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "sub",
      "type": "substrate",
      "id": "1",
      "endpoint": "ws://localhost:9944",
      "from": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
      "opts": {
          "useExtendedCall":"true"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- cb-sol.cli can deploy and setup Ethereum contracts that can receive incoming tokens: [ChainBridge: how to use their CLI tool to deploy smart contracts on Ethereum networks?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/chainbridge-how-to-use-their-cli-tool-to-deploy-smart-contracts-on-ethereum-net/)
- How to get/make those resource Ids in the "Register Resources Substrate" step:
  A Resource ID must be a 32-byte unique value to the resource. The Resource IDs are arbitrary, but they may have the originated from chain ID in the last byte. For example, this is a valid id if it is unique: "0x000000000000000000000000000000c76ebe4a02bbc34786d860b355f5a5ce00". The last "00" represents the chain ID this token was originated from.

Then...

- add chainbridge-substrate's example-pallet into my parachain
  ... I need to upgrade that pallet's code to newer syntax
- run relayers with updated config.json with new Ethereum addresses, new endpoints

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this [documentation](https://chainbridge.chainsafe.io/local/).

Comment: chainbridge-substrate's example-pallet is outdated. Use Centrifuge's repo. Thanks