# ChainBridge: how to use their CLI tool to deploy smart contracts on Ethereum networks?

Tags: smart-contract, ethereum, chainbridge

How to Ropsten, Rinkeby, Kovan, Goerli, and Kiln

From cb-sol-cli doc page https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-deploy/blob/master/cb-sol-cli/docs/deploy.md
It is not very clear or easy to use this cb-sol-cli tool.

I made one config file with all the public keys, private keys, and network RPC URLs, etc...

```
SRC_GATEWAY=https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/61c499d4d8ce4d7390c6fdcf623c460c
DST_GATEWAY=http://34.77.219.227/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F34.77.219.227%3A8844

SRC_ADDR="0xBB09..."
SRC_PK="7668fxxxxxxxxx...."
```

another bash script to run commands

```
cb-sol-cli --url $SRC_GATEWAY --privateKey $SRC_PK --gasPrice $GAS_PRICE deploy --bridge --erc20Handler --erc20 \
    --relayers $SRC_ADDR \
    --relayerThreshold 1 \
    --expiry 1000 \
    --chainId 0
```

when I ran those:

```
source ./configFile
./bashscript.sh
```

I got this error message

```
{
  e: Error: invalid response - 0
      at exports.XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/chainbridge-deploy/cb-sol-cli/node_modules/ethers/utils/web.js:84:29)
      at exports.XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/chainbridge-deploy/cb-sol-cli/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
      at setState (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/chainbridge-deploy/cb-sol-cli/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:610:14)
      at exports.XMLHttpRequest.handleError (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/chainbridge-deploy/cb-sol-cli/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:532:5)
      at ClientRequest.errorHandler (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/chainbridge-deploy/cb-sol-cli/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:459:14)
      at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3) {
    statusCode: 0,
    responseText: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80\n' +
      '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)'
  }
}
```

Is it okay to use Infura's URL as the cb-sol-cli --url <Infura's URL> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should run `source ./configFile` inside the bashscript.sh every time! Otherwise those variables cannot be read from the bash script for some reason.

Also check out those tutorials because the official tutorial does not cover public testnets like Ethereum Rinkeby:

https://docs.avax.network/subnets/deploying-cross-chain-evm-bridge#deploy-contracts

https://edge-docs.polygon.technology/docs/additional-features/chainbridge/deploy-contracts/